# Outlook, Word, and normal.dot (2003 Edition)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, macros, templates, microsoft-word

I have one user that for some reason has been having macro issues with her normal.dot file.  At first the fix was just remove the file because she isn't actually needing to save anything.  This was really a temp fix.

We found out that for some reason every time she opened up word it was trying to modify normal.dot but not asking.  I set it up to ask so at least we could control the changes going on to normal.dot.  There was one file disabled in Word that we enabled because it was a document she never used anymore, making us think that maybe that was the issue.

We have automatic antivirus updates and scans so there is little chance of a virus.

The issue has stopped as far as just using Word itself.  She can open, close, edit, save, etc and never get the dialog.

In Outlook however if she clicks reply or forward to an e-mail but decides not to send it, and just close it.  She gets the pop up to save changes to normal.dot.  This leads me to believe something in outlook about how she is setup to use Word as an e-mail editor is causing the problem.

Am I even on the right track here?

Short form:  Word works fine with normal.dot, as an Outlook mail editor wants to change normal.dot.  No idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Microsoft solution: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291352

*First, you can turn off the prompt and Word will automatically save the changes, but you may still have a problem.*

*Second, your Normal.dot or Normal.dotm template may be infected with a macro virus. To resolve this problem, you would need to install or update your virus protection software on your computer.*

*Third, you could have an add-in that is causing this problem. To resolve this problem, you may need to determine what add-in is causing the problem and remove it from the Office or Word startup folders.*

You can also check http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HA011514521033.aspx